# how to delete Signature object without prompt?

Tags: vba, ms-word

I'm currently studying the signature object (Word). This example will test to make sure that the digital signature that the user selects meets certain criteria, or else delete it. However, the `sig.delete` will prompt the user. Is there anyway to delete the signature object without prompt?

This example is from [Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/office.signature)

```
Function AddSignature(ByVal strIssuer As String, strSigner As String) As Boolean 

On Error GoTo Error_Handler 
 
 Dim sig As Signature 
 
 'Display the dialog box that lets the 
 'user select a digital signature. 
 'If the user selects a signature, then 
 'it is added to the Signatures 
 'collection. If the user does not, then 
 'an error is returned. 
 Set sig = ActiveDocument.Signatures.Add 
 
 'Test several properties before commiting the Signature object to disk. 
 If sig.Issuer = strIssuer And _ 
 sig.Signer = strSigner And _ 
 sig.IsCertificateExpired = False And _ 
 sig.IsCertificateRevoked = False And _ 
 sig.IsValid = True Then 
 
 MsgBox "Signed" 
 AddSignature = True 
 'Otherwise, remove the Signature object from the SignatureSet collection. 
 Else 
 sig.Delete 
 MsgBox "Not signed" 
 AddSignature = False 
 End If 
 
 'Commit all signatures in the SignatureSet collection to the disk. 
 ActiveDocument.Signatures.Commit 
 
 Exit Function 
Error_Handler: 
 AddSignature = False 
 MsgBox "Action canceled." 
End Function
```

Comment: Maybe [this can help](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32463451/11167163)

Comment: @TourEiffel - Outlook signatures are completely different to digital signatures.